# Trouble while declaring an element of view in its class file

Tags: ios, swift, view

I've a view controller which contains a view element like the following (the view is the orange element) :

[image]

The view is associated to a custom view class that I called "Quickie.swift". This view is an object with a textfield and a button so I want to declare both in the Quickie.swift.

However I can drag/drop to create declaration in the swift file :

[image]

And here nothing happen.

I can't find out how to declare this variable in my view object.

Comment: did you set the class of the view to `Quickie` in storyboard?

Comment: Yes I did, custom class is set on Quickie.

Comment: select Quickie view in storyboard and open assistant editor, it will show the Quickie class. Now you should be able to create outlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to write it by your own and drag it to the code?

@IBOutlet var view: UIView!

You Need to release r-Click on **view: UIView!**

Comment: I've just tried it and it doesn't worked. Nothing happened again.

Comment: or maybe write in the Utilities (right sidebar) under Class Quickie.

Comment: Ok wait. I think I've found.

Comment: It's ok, it works but I don't know why you have to wait about 30 seconds before drag on the view. Thank you man.